# SQL Server 2008 R2: Pivot table query performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

**Table**: Product

```
create table Product
(
    productID int,
    productName varchar(20),
    productsalesdate DATETIME,
    producttype varchar(20)
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
insert into product values(1,'PenDrive','2010-01-01','Electronic');
insert into product values(1,'Computer','2016-01-01','Electronic');
insert into product values(1,'Laptop','2011-02-02','Electronic');
insert into product values(2,'textbook','2014-02-02','books');
insert into product values(2,'notebook','2016-01-01','books');
insert into product values(3,'Car','2016-01-01','Vehicle');
insert into product values(3,'Bike','2016-01-07','Vehicle');
```

**First Try**: In this I am getting wrong sum of productType

```
SELECT productID, FirstSale,LastSale, [Electronic],[books],[Vehicle]
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        productID, 
        MIN(ProductSalesdate) as FirstSale,
        MAX(ProductSalesdate) as LastSale,
        productType
    FROM
        Product
    Group by productID,productType
) a 
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(productType) 
    FOR productType IN ( [Electronic],[books],[Vehicle] )
) AS pvt;
```

**Second Try**: In this try I have solved the sum problem but the query is taking more time for execute for huge records.

```
SELECT productID,FirstSale,LastSale ,[Electronic],[books],[Vehicle]
FROM
(
    SELECT a.ProductID, a.FirstSale, a.LastSale, b.ProductType
    FROM Product b
    inner join
    (
        SELECT 
            productID, 
            MIN(ProductSalesdate) as FirstSale,
            MAX(ProductSalesdate) as LastSale
        FROM
            Product
        Group by productID
    ) as a 
    ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
) ab 
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(productType) 
    FOR productType IN ( [Electronic],[books],[Vehicle] )
) AS pvt;
```

**Note**: The second query is works fine but the problem is with the performance, because of 
I am joining two same table because to get count of productType in the pivot query.

**Question**: How to optimize the second query which is a my second try?

Comment: Can products of a certain `productType` have the same `productId`?

Comment: Also, you have a derived table `a` in your second try, which groups on `productType, productId` but you join it with `b` only on `productId` ... seems fishy

Comment: You claim you have a problem with performance. Can you describe that please? It takes seconds, minutes, hours? What execution time did you expect?

Comment: Also, do you have proper `INDEX`es on table `Product`?

Comment: @TT, For 15k records it seems 10min of time and yeah i have `index` on `productID`.

Comment: If you analyse the execution plan, what does that tell you? Does it report any missing indices? Any table scans?

Comment: What you can do, is make 2 statements: the first inserts your derived table `ab` to a (local) temporary table; the second uses the temporary table to perform the pivot. It's highly likely your execution plan will improve drastically.

Comment: @TT, Okay! Thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: Any luck with the hint I gave?

Comment: @TT, Can you please post some code snippet for the same as a answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following uses a temporary table to store the derived table `ab`. My guess is it will improve the execution plan of the second query.

```
SELECT a.ProductID, a.FirstSale, a.LastSale, b.ProductType
INTO #ab
FROM Product b
inner join
(
    SELECT 
        productID, 
        MIN(ProductSalesdate) as FirstSale,
        MAX(ProductSalesdate) as LastSale
    FROM
        Product
    Group by productID
) as a 
ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID;

SELECT productID,FirstSale,LastSale ,[Electronic],[books],[Vehicle]
FROM #ab AS ab 
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(productType) 
    FOR productType IN ( [Electronic],[books],[Vehicle] )
) AS pvt;

DROP TABLE #ab;
```

---

EDIT: Just for sports I wrote following script which has 15k rows in #product. The whole script executes in ~1 second. I still don't understand how your query takes 5.5 minutes. Here goes:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #product (
    product_id INT,
    product_name VARCHAR(20),
    product_sales_date DATE,
    product_type VARCHAR(20)
);

DECLARE @cnt INT=0;
WHILE @cnt<15000
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #product(
        product_id,
        product_name,
        product_sales_date,
        product_type
    )
    SELECT 
        product_id=ROUND(20*RAND(),0),
        product_name=LEFT(NEWID(),20),
        product_sales_date=DATEADD(DAY,ROUND((-10+20*RAND()), 0),GETDATE()),
        product_type=
            CASE ROUND(2*RAND(),0)
                WHEN 0 THEN 'Electronic'
                WHEN 1 THEN 'books'
                ELSE 'Vehicle'
            END;

    SET @cnt=@cnt+1;
END

SELECT a.product_id, a.first_sale, a.last_sale, b.product_type
INTO #ab
FROM #product b
inner join
(
    SELECT 
        product_id, 
        MIN(product_sales_date) as first_sale,
        MAX(product_sales_date) as last_sale
    FROM
        #product
    GROUP BY
        product_id
) as a 
ON a.product_id= b.product_id;

SELECT product_id,first_sale,last_sale,[Electronic],[books],[Vehicle]
FROM #ab AS ab 
PIVOT
(
    COUNT(product_type) 
    FOR product_type IN ( [Electronic],[books],[Vehicle] )
) AS pvt;

DROP TABLE #ab;
DROP TABLE #product;
```

Comment: It's now 5.5 min. Which mean much for me.

Comment: @MAK Ouch that's still a lot. Maybe you can put an appropriate KEY/INDEX on the temporary table? That requires that your first CREATE the temporary table and add indices on it (just like you would create and add indices on a regular table). Then the first statement would become `INSERT INTO #ab(...cols...) SELECT ...` (without the INTO #ab).

Comment: @MAK You could for instance analyze the actual execution plan (in SSMS, click the 'Include Actual Execution Plan' button in the toolbar). See if it proposes any indices.

Comment: @MAK Added a test script in my answer that has 15k rows, same pivot query runs in 1 second.

Comment: Hey thank you so much! Will test it tomorrow and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to do something like this.. Not sure why you'd need extra joins or temp tables..

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT  productID, 
            productType,
            MIN(ProductSalesdate) as FirstSale,
            MAX(ProductSalesdate) as LastSale,
            COUNT(productType) AS ProductCount
    FROM Product
    GROUP BY productID,productType
) t
PIVOT 
(
    SUM(ProductCount)
    FOR productType IN ([Electronic],[books],[Vehicle])
) p
```

you'll get NULLS for the 0 counts but you can coalesce those values to 0 pretty easily

Comment: The OP had performance problems with his PIVOT query, that's why I suggested materializing the derived table to a temporary table first. Could very well be that your version does better.

Comment: @TT. from what I've noticed lately on here, pivot itself has performance issues and it's better to use those ugly aggregates with case statements

Comment: Very true. I can refer you to this [thread on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34770562/243373) in which a badly performing PIVOT was optimized using a combination of old-school PIVOT (using CASE) along with OPTION(HASH GROUP) to speed up the grouping.