# performance improvement on Pivoting script

Tags: sql-server, performance, pivot

In my data generation procedure I have a temporary table with about 100M rows. 
Table's structure is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #table ( ProductId INT, CountryCodeID INT ,DataTypeID INT,
     Formula VARCHAR(1000) ,Yr INT, Letter VARCHAR(100) , Data FLOAT(53))
```

We can populate it with some dummy data (~10M):

```
INSERT INTO #table ( ProductId, CountryCodeID, DataTypeID, Formula, Yr, Letter, Data )
SELECT
     P.ProductID, C.CountryCodeID, D.DataTypeID, F.Formula, Y.Yr,
     L.Letter, RAND() AS Data
FROM (VALUES (
    1856),(1459),(1816),(238),(328),(444),(921),(1724),(155),(420),(795),
    (620),(1007),(153),(1659),(95),(952),(1476),(759),(1461),(1958),(1341),
    (116)) P(productID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (16),(302),(422),(36),(95),(744),(4),(285),(1849),(1402),
    (430),(835),(214),(1476),(711),(36),(142),(428),(768),(78),(510),(945),
    (1125)) C(CountryCodeID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1120),(1121),(1122),(1123),(1124),(1125),(1126),(1127),
    (1128)) D(DataTypeID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('A+B'),('A/B/(A+B+C+D+E+G)'),('A/B/(A+B+C+D+E)'),
    ('A/B/(A+B+C+D)'),('A/B/(A+B+C)'),('A/B/(A+B)'),
    ('A/B/(A+B+C+D+E+G+Z)')) F(Formula)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1977),(1978),(1979),(1980),(1981),(1982),(1983),(1984),
    (1985),(1986),(1987),(1988), (2000),(2001),(2002),(2003),        (2004),
    (2005),(2006),(2007),(2008),(2009),(2010),(2011),(2012),(2013)) Y(Yr)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('J '),
    ('K'),('L'),('M')) L(Letter) 
--10 398 024
```

In the end of my procedure I need to Pivot my table to another temporary table:

```
SELECT
     ProductID,CountryCodeId,DataTypeID,Formula,
    Yr,A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,X,Z,W
INTO #Final3
FROM #table
PIVOT ( MAX(Data) FOR Letter IN (
     A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,X,Z,W
    ) ) AS pvt;
```

And the last query is extremely slow. It takes literally ages.

Execution plan:
[image]

there is table scan in the beginning but only 2% 
table insert into #Final takes 83%

[image]
Interesting that estimated nr of rows much bigger than actual number of rows.

So my question is how can I improve performance. Some of my ideas:

- Indexes?;
- Maybe it can help to divide `#table` into 10 smaller tables using `NTILE` and after that create a loop which will perform 10 pivots?

To be honest I don't have any other ideas ... If you have relevant experience - please advice. 
Thanks.

Comment: `Maybe it is worth to try with variable tables instead of temporary tables? (data will be stored in memory and it will save writing to disk time)` [Yes, Table Variables and Temp Tables both use the tempdb](http://cybersql.blogspot.com/2009/12/yes-table-variables-and-temp-tables.html)

Comment: You should try an index on `ProductId, CountryCodeId, Yr, Data`.

Comment: @lad2025 yes... you are right. and it takes even longer ...

Comment: Are you aware that your scipt generates the same value for RAND() for each cell [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/422901)?

Comment: @lad2025 yes, in my system they are all different ... added like this not to waste much time creating dummy data

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have tried both nonclustered and clustered indexes. Clustered index didn't change performace. Nonclustered runs much longer in comparison with query without indexes

Comment: Have you tried an INDEX on Letter (maybe Letter+Data), since you appear to be selecting the `MAX(Data) FOR Letter IN (...)`? Is this a real-world problem you are trying to fix?

Comment: @TT. yes it is real world problem. the only difference is that I have much more rows 100M-150M. so this query takes around 50 minutes. I really want to reduce this time.  Should it be nonclustered index?

Comment: @TT. with nonclustered index it takes 3 times longer ... execution plan is the same: http://prntscr.com/9pkhdr

Comment: @Almazini How about partitioning your table and have clustered index

Comment: Are Formula and Letter foreign keys into other tables? I ask because the maximum width of these fields is impacting your index height, a likely constraint on how performant this pivot can be. If there is actually a small set of values for one or both of these fields, such that a foreign key into a lookup table can be substituted for them in #table, then your performance should improve dramatically.  Also, does your server have *tempdb* on an SSD?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens the lenght of Formula column is taken according to maxim possible lenght of data in it. I tried to change it to Varchar(300) and nothing has changed

Comment: @RyanVincent unfortunately the issue is with last query. first query here is only for those who will try to test on their machine. In real world there are other queries which take only 5% of the whole SP and the last one (pivot and insert) takes 95% of time. according to execution plan insert part takes 85% ... and estimated number of rows much more than actual number of rows. maybe this is the issue. but i Fail to achieve same figures in execution plan.

Comment: But I return to my key question: What is the actual significance of Formula and Letter?  Asked because any performance improvement of this query is going to have to leverage that knowledge in order to reduce the handling time of these long strings. That is the significance of the heavy INSERT time in the query plan.

Comment: Perhaps you are using the wrong tool to PIVOT? You could consider [Matrices (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149.aspx) or [OLAP cubes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916543.aspx). I got these suggestions [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6fd3c90a-895f-4a37-8804-75a092ca0807/performance-of-sql-pivot-query-against-large-tables?forum=transactsql).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens the idea is the following: to calculate productID each product has a formula. each letter of this formulas has a value.

Comment: @Almazini: What! Put your temp tables into 3rd Normal Form before pivoting them. Your test data is completely invalid - no wonder you are getting terrible performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried using the old-school PIVOTing (using CASE) and got better results on my system (2~3 times faster). Also created a CLUSTERED INDEX, so inserting data will be a lot slower (for this test, SQL Server complains about the key length). Try it out and see if it improves your business case.

Hope this helps. If it doesn't please use my suggestions about using [Reporting Matrices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207149.aspx) or [OLAP Cubes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh916543.aspx). Also check this link: [Pivot Transformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140308.aspx). If you can't use those, maybe even coding the PIVOT yourself in your programming language might perform better.

Test data creation (used global temp so I could test selection in second tab in SSMS):

```
CREATE TABLE ##table ( ProductId INT, CountryCodeID INT ,DataTypeID INT, Formula VARCHAR(1000) ,Yr INT, Letter VARCHAR(100) , Data FLOAT(53));
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX tt ON ##table(ProductId, CountryCodeID, DataTypeID,Formula,Yr);

INSERT INTO ##table ( ProductId, CountryCodeID, DataTypeID, Formula, Yr, Letter, Data )
SELECT P.ProductID, C.CountryCodeID, D.DataTypeID, F.Formula, Y.Yr, L.Letter, RAND() AS Data
FROM (VALUES (1856),(1459),(1816),(238),(328),(444),(921),(1724),(155),(420),(795),(620),(1007),(153),(1659),(95),(952),(1476),(759),(1461),(1958),(1341),(116)) P(productID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (16),(302),(422),(36),(95),(744),(4),(285),(1849),(1402),(430),(835),(214),(1476),(711),(36),(142),(428),(768),(78),(510),(945),(1125)) C(CountryCodeID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1120),(1121),(1122),(1123),(1124),(1125),(1126),(1127),(1128)) D(DataTypeID)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('A+B'),('A/B/(A+B+C+D+E+G)'),('A/B/(A+B+C+D+E)'),('A/B/(A+B+C+D)'),('A/B/(A+B+C)'),('A/B/(A+B)'),('A/B/(A+B+C+D+E+G+Z)')) F(Formula)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (1977),(1978),(1979),(1980),(1981),(1982),(1983),(1984),(1985),(1986),(1987),(1988), (2000),(2001),(2002),(2003),(2004),(2005),(2006),(2007),(2008),(2009),(2010),(2011),(2012),(2013)) Y(Yr)
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('E'),('F'),('G'),('H'),('J '),('K'),('L'),('M')) L(Letter) ;
```

Generating the data in `#final3`:

```
SELECT 
    ProductID,
    CountryCodeId,
    DataTypeID,
    Formula,
    Yr,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='A' THEN Data END) AS A,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='B' THEN Data END) AS B,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='C' THEN Data END) AS C,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='D' THEN Data END) AS D,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='E' THEN Data END) AS E,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='F' THEN Data END) AS F,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='G' THEN Data END) AS G,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='H' THEN Data END) AS H,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='J' THEN Data END) AS J,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='K' THEN Data END) AS K,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='L' THEN Data END) AS L,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Letter='M' THEN Data END) AS M
INTO 
    #Final3
FROM 
    ##table
GROUP BY
    ProductID,
    CountryCodeId,
    DataTypeID,
    Formula,
    Yr
ORDER BY 
    ProductID,
    CountryCodeID,
    Yr;
```

Comment: Was trying this trick at the same time and was surprised that it helps! For me it works better without indexes!

Comment: @Almazini Some statistics on my system (portable; win 8.1 pro; SQL Server 2012 SP2; CPU=i7-4500U @1.8Ghz; 2 cores, logical processors=4; 16Gb; Samsung SSD 840 EVO **1) Without clustered index:** 1A) Inserting data: CPU time=14563ms, 1B) PIVOT: CPU time=62250ms, 1C) CASE: CPU time=48406ms. `     ` **2) With clustered index:** 2A) Inserting data: CPU time=105422ms; 2B) PIVOT: CPU time=52078ms 2C) CASE: CPU time=20656ms. Anyway, IO is probably a factor too...

Comment: @Almazini Another hint: if you don't have a clustered index, you may want to add the following at the end of the query: `OPTION(HASH GROUP)`. For both the PIVOT & the CASE version of the query, I got a substantial improvement in execution time. 1) PIVOT: CPU time=40109ms (compared to 62250ms), and 2) CASE: CPU time=25984ms (compared to 48406ms).

Comment: @Almazini To make the comparison complete, `OPTION(HASH GROUP)` with clustered index: 1) PIVOT: CPU time=37703ms (compared to 52078ms), and 2) CASE: CPU time=36781ms (compared to 20656ms). So adding this option for the case with a clustered index, improves the PIVOT query but makes the CASE query worse... Anyway, you have some new options to play with now ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot! In real life application all these little things helped to reduce execution time from 50 minutes to 10 minutes :) and it was really interesting deep investigation :)

Comment: @Almazini It's good to hear that. Did the OPTION help you in any way?

Comment: by the way, why are you using ORDER BY clause?:)

Comment: @Almazini Because you had one in your original PIVOT query =). I'm assuming since you mention it that you improved your query by removing it?

Comment: TT: Yes, sure we don't need any ordering in table with 80M rows:) Have no clue why I had it there!